# How do I build git on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3?

Tags: linux, git, redhat

When you try to build git v1.7.0.6 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3, you get an error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:179,
             from git-compat-util.h:139,
             from builtin.h:4,
             from fast-import.c:147:
/usr/include/openssl/kssl.h:72:18: krb5.h: No such file or directory
```

I have the answer to this, and I'm just posting it here for posterity.

Comment: +1, but it might be better suited for the serverfault audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to run ./configure with a flag to tell it where to find krb5.h:

```
./configure CFLAGS='-I/usr/kerberos/include'
```